# Maven Deploy via SFTP not working

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to deploy my maven Java project to an internal repository I have created.

I am using Ubuntu on my dev machine and I can connect to the Repo with the following command:

```
ftp -P7123 maven_repo@my_domain.com
```

This gives me a working connection. I am using a non standard port and public keys to log in as user maven_repo.

My project is in eclipse and I am using the eclipse built in m2e to run maven.

I added the sections into my pom.xml file:

```
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>ssh-repository</id>
      <url>scpexe://mvn.metcarob.com:7456/public</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

and

```
<extensions>
  <!-- Enabling the use of SSH -->
  <extension>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
     <artifactId>wagon-ssh-external</artifactId>
     <version>1.0-beta-6</version>
  </extension>
</extensions>
```

My install had no ~/.m2/settings.xml and I have read that it is not there by default and I need to create it so I created it as: (Based on online examples)

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                          https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
      <localRepository/>
      <interactiveMode/>
      <usePluginRegistry/>
      <offline/>
      <pluginGroups/>
      <servers>
          <server>
              <id>ssh-repository</id>
              <username>maven_repo</username>
              <privateKey>/home/robert/.ssh/id_rsa</privateKey>
          </server>
      </servers>
      <mirrors/>
      <proxies/>
      <profiles/>
      <activeProfiles/>
    </settings>
```

When I run the deploy goal I get the following errors:

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) artifact = metcarob.com.BobDiary:BobDiary:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   (f) attachedArtifacts = [metcarob.com.BobDiary:BobDiary:jar:jar-with-dependencies:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
[DEBUG]   (s) localRepository =       id: local
      url: file:///home/robert/.m2/repository/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => always]

[DEBUG]   (f) offline = false
[DEBUG]   (f) packaging = jar
[DEBUG]   (f) pomFile = /home/robert/eclipse/BobProjects/BobDiary/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: metcarob.com.BobDiary:BobDiary:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ /home/robert/eclipse/BobProjects/BobDiary/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) retryFailedDeploymentCount = 1
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) updateReleaseInfo = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.ssh.external.ScpExternalWagon
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/util/cli/CommandLineException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
    ... (More removed)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.956 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-16T10:35:28+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/407M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project BobDiary: Execution default-deploy of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy: org/codehaus/plexus/util/cli/CommandLineException
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/home/robert/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/home/robert/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/home/robert/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.6/plexus-utils-1.5.6.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>metcarob.com.BobDiary:BobDiary:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineException
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project BobDiary: Execution default-deploy of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy: org/codehaus/plexus/util/cli/CommandLineException
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/home/robert/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.jar
urls[1] = file:/home/robert/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
urls[2] = file:/home/robert/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.6/plexus-utils-1.5.6.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>metcarob.com.BobDiary:BobDiary:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
```

Can anyone help me getting this working?

**Update 1
I changed the extension in my POM file to:

```
  <extension>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
     <artifactId>wagon-ssh-external</artifactId>
     <version>2.10</version>
  </extension>
```

and I am now getting a different error:

```
INFO] Downloading: scpexe://mvn.metcarob.com:7456/public/metcarob/com/BobDiary/BobDiary/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata metcarob.com.BobDiary:BobDiary:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to ssh-repository (scpexe://mvn.metcarob.com:7456/public): Exit code: 1 - Host key verification failed.

org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataTransferException: Could not transfer metadata metcarob.com.BobDiary:BobDiary:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to ssh-repository (scpexe://mvn.metcarob.com:7456/public): Exit code: 1 - Host key verification failed.

    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.MetadataTransportListener.transferFailed(MetadataTransportListener.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
```

This is "Host key verification failed". 
I have a few questions:
I need it to use sftp not scp, the command:

```
scp -P7456 maven_repo@metcarob.com:/public/settings.xml settings.xml
```

will fail for my repo due to security settings.

I do not see where in the command I can tell it to use sftp rather than ssh or scp.

Comment: Why are you using such extreme old version of wagon ? Current version of Wagon is 2.10 http://maven.apache.org/wagon/ Furthermore why not using an existing repository manager like Nexus ?

Comment: I copied my extension from http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ssh-external.html I will try and find an example with 2.1 and copy that

Comment: I have googled for nexus and came up with http://www.sonatype.com/download-oss-sonatype My web server is a cheap online one with only 512mb of ram and already has a tonne of stuff on it. I don't want to use any more than a simple file based repo for now. Nexus is something I will look into in the future.

Comment: I can recommend to use Nexus OSS cause it makes things easier..Furthermore you can use it on your own machine..Why do you need an online server ? Do you like to publish open source ? Than better think about Maven Central...

Comment: I develop on a few different machines and I also use GitLab Continuous Integration to compile so I need it to be available so it can get at the artefacts. These are my own personal projects and I doubt they are any interest to anyone else.

Comment: So best is to use Nexus OS which helps in many areas, cause an scp server is not a Maven repository...Apart from that you don't know if someone is interested in...You can also use github includes issue system and for example Travis-ci for building ?

Comment: It isn't just scp. I also have Apache serving the files via HTTPS. I just don't want to upload via SSH because I can't lock the upload user into a sperfic directory.

Comment: Which you can do with a repository manager like Nexus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the complete answer.
I made two mistakes. 
1. Wrong version for wagon-ssh-external
2. Host Key verification wasn't working.

1 was an easy fix just changing the number in the pom file.
2 is a bit more complex. There is a file called known_hosts in the users ~/.ssh directory. My main user on my development machine has this file but the maven deploy must be using a different file, maybe it is running under another user. I fixed this by pointing it at my main known_hosts file which had the key in it.

Working file sections are:
Pom.xml:

```
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>ssh-repository</id>
            <name>ssh-repository</name>
      <url>scpexe://mvn.metcarob.com:7456/public</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

... Build section ...

```
<extensions>
  <!-- Enabling the use of SSH -->
  <extension>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
     <artifactId>wagon-ssh-external</artifactId>

     <version>2.10</version>
  </extension>
</extensions>
```

working settings.xml:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                          https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
      <localRepository/>
      <interactiveMode/>
      <usePluginRegistry/>
      <offline/>
      <pluginGroups/>
      <servers>
          <server>
              <id>ssh-repository</id>
              <username>maven_repo</username>
              <configuration>
                  <sshExecutable>plink</sshExecutable>
                  <scpExecutable>sftp</scpExecutable>
                  <sshArgs></sshArgs>
                  <scpArgs>-o UserKnownHostsFile=/home/robert/.ssh/known_hosts</scpArgs>
              </configuration>
            <!-- <filePermissions>664</filePermissions>
            <directoryPermissions>775</directoryPermissions> -->
          </server>
      </servers>
      <mirrors/>
      <proxies/>
      <profiles/>
      <activeProfiles/>
</settings>
```